# Random number generation using rnorm

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a  normally distributed random number that doesn't exceed a certain value while being normally distributed. I came up with the below:

```
expenses <- pmax(850, rnorm(1000, income*0.4, income*0.1))
```

how would I add to this so it doesn't exceed 1500?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expenses <- pmin(1500, pmax(850, rnorm(1000, income*0.4, income*0.1)))
```